# Flutter Firebase: Is it possible to exclude properties from a stream?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I listen to a stream a products, to update data for an enduser app.

`Stream<QuerySnapshot<ProductModel>>`

I want to have statistic properties like amountOfSales for the administrator.
But the stream should not be notified that a product got updated.
Some properties are not relevant for the enduser.

Does something like an exclude annotation exist for properties in firebase for flutter?
Or do i need to create an extra collection for each product where i have properties for each product which the enduser should not have?

I found those annotations for Kotlin, but nothing for flutter.
(Not sure if these annotations for kotlin would be what i need for flutter)
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/database/Exclude

Comment: You can't exclude fields from results when using the web or mobile SDKs, and any field changed in a document will trigger a realtime update in the client.  If you must only allow a view of certain fields, you can have two collections with different sets of fields depending on what you want the client to have. The @Exclude annotation for Java does not do that - it merely excludes them from being written from a data model.